# F# Type provider FSharp,Data.SqlClient targeting .NetStandard 2.0 fails when using dotNet Build from commandLine but succeeds in Visual Studion 2019

Tags: f#, .net-standard-2.0, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I am using the F# Type Provider FSharp.Data.SqlClient in a DLL targeting .Net-Standard-2.0, while this successfully builds in Visual Studio 2019  it fails when I try to build it using the command prompt compiler dotNet compiler with the following error message

```
J:\Workspaces\DRILQUIP_2456764.0\Applications\EngWeb\Dev\src\EngWeb.Core\BillOfDocuments\BillOfDocumentsDataAccess.fs(14,27): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.SqlProgrammabilityProvider' reported an error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058) [J:\Workspaces\DRILQUIP_2456764.0\Applications\EngWeb\Dev\src\EngWeb.Core\EngWeb.Core.fsproj]
J:\Workspaces\DRILQUIP_2456764.0\Applications\EngWeb\Dev\src\EngWeb.Core\BillOfDocuments\BillOfDocumentsDataAccess.fs(14,27): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.SqlProgrammabilityProvider' reported an error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
```

I am using FSharp.Data.SqlClient version 2.0.6  and System.Data.SqlClient Version 4.8.1 and the FSharp.Core version 4.7.0

Any help with this issue will be appreciated

Comment: First try to delete bin and obj directories and let the dotnet compiler build all dependencies from scratch. If that does not solve the problem then a deeper look into https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23174 might be useful.